# Netty + SQS Integrationtests: Failed to submit a listener notification task. Event loop shut down?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, amazon-sqs

I am trying to test an SQS queue in my Spring Boot application using `SpringBootTest`. The test itself only tests the startup of the application:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationTest {
    
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {}
    
}
```

I have the queue configured as a bean normally. Now running this results in the following error:

```
Error: Failed to submit a listener notification task. Event loop shut down?
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:926)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.offerTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:346)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:828)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:818)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.safeExecute(DefaultPromise.java:842)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:499)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.CancellableAcquireChannelPool.lambda$acquire$1(CancellableAcquireChannelPool.java:58)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.access$200(DefaultPromise.java:35)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$1.run(DefaultPromise.java:502)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

The test still succeeds but I do not know how to get rid of this error. I can even send messages to the queue during testing and everything works fine.

Comment: Can you fix it? I have the same problem here!